# How to get Data from API to display chart using chartjs in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, linechart

I am new to Vuejs and i wanna know how to fetch data from my API to display chart.

Below is my code, where i have used data as "date and challenge" and have fed data directly to it, but now i want to call my API and feed the data from it to "date and challenge".

Code that i have used it to display chart without API:

```
<template>
  <canvas id="mychart" width="550" height="300"></canvas>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Chart',
  data: () => ({
    date: [
      1600934100.0,
      1602009600.0,
      1602747060.0,
      1603050158.390939,
      1603305573.992575
    ],
    challenge: [
      9.0,
      9.5,
      2.5,
      11.52,
      12.4
    ]
  }),
  mounted () {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
      x: new Date(date * 1000),
      y: this.challenge[index]
    }))

    const ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d')
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-unused-vars
    const Chart_2 = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            data,
            label: 'Chart from API ',
            borderColor: '#7367F0'
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'month',
                displayFormats: {
                  month: 'MMM YYYY'
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                callback (value, index, values) {
                  return `${value  }%`
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I know to get API we use 'axios' or 'fetch' , so whenever i get API and just do console.log(response.data) i will get my data in the console in my browser, but further i dont know to map it and use those data to feed "date and chalenge" in order to display chart.

Here is my API:

My API which contains data in it: `https://api.wirespec.dev/wirespec/stackoverflow/fetchchartdataforvuejs`

Please someone help me to display chart by using my API in my code.

Comment: Check out this example under the vue-chartjs documentation: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer Hoorah!

I am sharing, how I did it even you can do the same in order to visualize chart with your API data.

```
<template>
  <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height: 25vh; width:100%;">
    <canvas id="DisplayChart" ></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
  name: 'Chart_from_API',
  data () {
    return {
      myChart: []
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    await this.$http.get('https://api.wirespec.dev/wirespec/stackoverflow/fetchchartdataforvuejs') //Your API has to be given here
      .then((response) => {
        const result = response.data
        const ctx = document.getElementById('DisplayChart').getContext('2d')
        const Chart_data = []
        for (let i = 0; i < result.date.length; i++) {
          Chart_data.push({
            x_axis: moment(result.date[i], 'X').toDate(),  //To Convert Unix Timestamp into Date
            y_axis: result.challenge[i]
          })
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line init-declarations,prefer-const
        let myChart
        if (myChart !== undefined) {
          myChart.destroy()
        }

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Chart_from_API',
                data: Chart_data,
                borderColor: '#EA5455',
                lineTension: 0
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            lineTension: 0,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                    callback (value) {
                      return `${value  }k`    // y-axis value will append k to it
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  type: 'time',
                  time: {
                    unit: 'month'
                  },
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: ''
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried like this one?

**solution 1**

Add `async/await` so it will wait until the data get populated to `data` and `challege`.

```js
async mounted () {
    let result = await axios.get('https://api.wirespec.dev/wirespec/stackoverflow/fetchchartdataforvuejs')
    this.date = result.data.date
    this.challenge = result.data.challenge

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
      x: new Date(date * 1000),
      y: this.challenge[index]
    }))

    const ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d')
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-unused-vars
    const Chart_2 = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            data,
            label: 'Chart from API ',
            borderColor: '#7367F0'
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'month',
                displayFormats: {
                  month: 'MMM YYYY'
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                callback (value, index, values) {
                  return `${value  }%`
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

or in another way, you can fetch the data from API in other component and send `date` and `challege` as props to this component.

**solution 2**

I assume you have chart component `chart.vue`

**chart.vue**

```js
<template>
  <canvas id="mychart" width="550" height="300"></canvas>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Chart',

  props: ['date', 'challenge],

  data: () => ({

  }),
  mounted () {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
      x: new Date(date * 1000),
      y: this.challenge[index]
    }))

    const ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d')
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-unused-vars
    const Chart_2 = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            data,
            label: 'Chart from API ',
            borderColor: '#7367F0'
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'month',
                displayFormats: {
                  month: 'MMM YYYY'
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                callback (value, index, values) {
                  return `${value  }%`
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

and in other component, import your **chart.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <Chart v-if="!isLoading" :date="date" :challenge="challenge" />
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    import Chart from 'PATH TO chart.vue'
    export default {
        components: {
            Chart
        },
        data () => ({
            date: [],
            challenge: [],
            isLoading: false
        }),
        methods: {
            async getData () {
                this.isLoading = true
                let result = await axios.get(API URL)
                this.date = result.data.date
                this.challenge = result.data.challenge
                this.isLoading = false
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.getData()
        }
    }
</script>
```

In **chart.vue**, delete `date` and `challege` from `data` because you will have `props`, for the best practice `props` and `data` cannot have same property name.

In other component where **chart.vue** get imported, just fetch the data as usual.

Things I did when I was using chartjs for my project, I always add `v-if` in , it will let the axios fetch the data first and then re-mount the chart component. Because I guess chartjs is not reactive on vuejs data changes, so will need to update the data first then re-mount again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i had tried this earlier also, but even this is not working, if i do like this i get error as vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". Please can you tell is there any other way that i can display my chart from API. And can you also tell me what should be given in data () => ({ date: '?' challenge: '?' )} because in datasets i have specified it has 'data'

Comment: make sure you didnt get cors problems, I tried it on codesandbox and got cors error

Comment: I tried 2nd solution, but nothing was displayed in chart, and there is no error in console also, don't know what i should do now, i have been trying different ways to solve it, but not able to display the chart from API

Comment: did it work with static data without API?

Comment: try using this https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#example

Comment: I tried it, but it dint work out, don't know where i am going wrong , but I'm able to console log my API and able to see my data in the console window. Can you please give me some other solution, i am able to see my chart but my data from API is not rendering to chart. Please help me solve this, I am stuck with this.

Comment: Thank you @kusiaga, for your efforts, i got the answer from your solution 1 but had to do certain changes in order to get the results.

Comment: please check my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-leakey-e7pip?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue . because I got cors problems, assume `add data` is calling an API. overal it should work with API

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vue-chartjs` which is a wrapper for [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) in Vue.

Install it over the `npm` package manager.

```
npm install vue-chartjs chart.js
```

According to the [documentation](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data), there is a common problem when accessing the data from an asynchronous API endpoint:

> The problem with this approach is that Chart.js tries to render your chart and access the chart data **synchronously**, so your **chart mounts before the API data arrives**.

To prevent this, a simple `v-if` is the best solution. The following Vue component utilizes a boolean variable to stop the chart mounting before the data arrives.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Stock Data</h1>
    <!-- The v-if is used to conditionally render a block -->
    <Bar id="my-chart-id" v-if="loaded" :options="chartOptions" :data="chartData" :width="600" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  data: () => ({
    // Prevents chart to mount before the API data arrives
    loaded: false,
    chartData: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'My Label',
          data: [],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
        }
      ]
    },
    chartOptions: {
      responsive: true
    }
  }),
  async mounted() {
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/data'

    // Make an HTTP request to fetch the data from the API endpoint
    await fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // Extract data from the API response and update the chartData
        this.chartData.labels = data.map((stock) => stock.date)
        this.chartData.datasets[0].data = data.map((stock) => stock.value)

        // Allow the chart to display the data from the API endpoint
        this.loaded = true
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

The key is to render the bar chart only if the data is arrived successfully. It is achieved by setting the `loaded` variable to true. Note that, you need to reload the page whenever new data is arrived.